# Multiple IN operator mysql combine

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to ask can I combine multiple IN operator with AND query?I need your help with my codes.Here is my code that I have tried but not working.

```
if ($areas != '' || $city_check != '' || $course != '' || $subject_check != '') {
        $countcity = count($city_check);
        $countsubject = count($subject_check);

        $area_ids = implode(',',$city_check);
        $subject_ids = implode(',',$subject_check);

        $sql .= "AND TAC.tac_st_id = '".$areas."' AND TAC.tac_city_id IN($area_ids) 
                AND TRS.trs_tc_id = '".$course."' AND TRS.trs_ts_id IN($subject_ids)
                GROUP BY U.u_username
                HAVING COUNT(distinct TAC.tac_city_id) = '".$countcity."' COUNT(distinct TRS.trs_ts_id) = '".$countsubject."'
                ";
    }
```

It produce no result.

I have done below code that working like I want but it can only run each blocks inside if.So if I want to search for city_check, the subject_check will not working and vice versa.

```
//search for cities
// if ($areas != '' || $city_check != '') {

    //     $countcity = count($city_check);

    //     $sql .= "AND TAC.tac_st_id = '".$areas."' AND TAC.tac_city_id IN(".implode(',',$city_check).")
    //             GROUP BY U.u_username
    //             HAVING COUNT(distinct TAC.tac_city_id) = '".$countcity."'
    //             ";
    // }

//search for subject
    // if ($course != '' || $subject_check != '') {

    //     $countsubject = count($subject_check);
    //     // echo json_encode(["message"=>$countcity]);

    //     $sql .= "AND TRS.trs_tc_id = '".$course."' AND TRS.trs_ts_id IN(".implode(',',$subject_check).")
    //             GROUP BY U.u_username
    //             HAVING COUNT(distinct TRS.trs_ts_id) = '".$countsubject."'
    //             ";

    //         }
```

What I want is that both cities and subject can be search together.Thank you for your help in advanced..

Edit: I try to output my SQL in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT U.u_username,U.u_email,U.u_status,ST.st_name,CT.city_name,TC.tc_title,TS.ts_title
FROM tk_user as U
INNER JOIN tk_user_details    AS UD  ON UD.ud_u_id   = U.u_id

LEFT JOIN tk_tutor_subject AS TRS ON TRS.trs_u_id = U.u_id 
LEFT JOIN tk_tution_course   AS TC  ON TC.tc_id     = TRS.trs_tc_id  
LEFT JOIN tk_tution_subject   AS TS  ON TS.ts_id     = TRS.trs_ts_id
LEFT JOIN tk_tutor_area_cover AS TAC ON TAC.tac_u_id = U.u_id 
LEFT JOIN tk_cities CT ON CT.city_id   = UD.ud_city AND TAC.tac_city_id = CT.city_id  
LEFT JOIN tk_states AS ST ON TAC.tac_st_id = ST.st_id
LEFT JOIN tk_countries AS C ON ST.st_c_id = C.c_id AND CT.city_c_id = C.c_id

WHERE U.u_status <> 'D'
AND TAC.tac_st_id = 1046 AND TAC.tac_city_id IN(16,17)
AND TRS.trs_tc_id = 5 AND TRS.trs_ts_id IN(8,9)

GROUP BY U.u_username
HAVING COUNT(distinct TAC.tac_city_id) = 2 AND COUNT(distinct TRS.trs_ts_id) = 2
```

[image: This the query result should look like]

[image: This is my search function checkbox that those query for]

[image: This is my echo $sql look like]

Comment: echo $sql before running it. How does it look?

Comment: do NOT build queries by concatenation! use **parameterized statements** or you'll be wide open for **sql injection** and a wide range of bugs!

Comment: hi  delboy1978uk..i try to echo but it does not show anything.

Comment: Franz Gleichmann..thank you for your respond.I will try to use your suggestion.

Comment: If you are combining with AND you will reduce your result so every clause MUST be fulfilled. Best would be if you can provide how your result should look like and how the SQL looks like. As @delboy1978uk mentioned do a >>> echo $sql <<< at the end of your file...

Comment: You should start by replacing `$areas != '' || $city_check != '' || $course != '' || $subject_check != ''` by `$areas != '' && $city_check != '' && $course != '' & $subject_check != ''` no? You want none of those $var to be empty?

Comment: hi michael.i have edited my post as I try to output my query that should work inside phpmyadmin.

Comment: Hi Mickael Leger..($areas,$city_check) is one set, and ($course.$subject_check) is another set. bot set can be empty as this is a search function. It can be empty either..

Comment: @Luqman305 I postet an answer, I'm not fully sure I did unterstand your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of them could be empty you should use something like that:

Use `OR`

```
...
WHERE U.u_status <> 'D' 
    AND 
    (
        (TAC.tac_st_id = 1046 AND TAC.tac_city_id IN(16,17) )
        OR 
        (TRS.trs_tc_id = 5 AND TRS.trs_ts_id IN(8,9) )
    )
...
```

Comment: thanx for your reply, but your code do not work on my code.although I have tried to use it in phpmyadmin and it does work..My problem is that when I run this ONLY (TAC.tac_st_id = 1046 AND TAC.tac_city_id IN(16,17) ), it work, same as (TRS.trs_tc_id = 5 AND TRS.trs_ts_id IN(8,9) ) ONLY, but when I try to combine both codes, It does not produce any results.. But still thank you.

Comment: How do you combine them? With AND?

Comment: @Luqman305 Fine :) If you think the answer is the solution, please mark it as solution so it can help other users. Cheers